# Reuse values entered in Tkinter GUI for further programming

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am currently kind of stuck at the crucial point of the program — we have created a GUI that lets the user choose what population model they want to use, and then lets them enter the values in entry boxes.
I now want those values to be reused in a further function. This is how I kind of imagine how it should work.

If x was chosen:

- do this with the values entered
- draw this graph

Here is the actual code for the GUI:

```
from tkinter import *
from math import *

class GUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root      = Tk()
        self.labelVariable = StringVar()
        self.root.title('Projet informatique')
        self.initialize()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def initialize(self):
        self.main = Frame(self.root)
        self.main.pack()

        label = Label(self.main, textvariable=self.labelVariable, font=('courier',10,'bold'), anchor="w", fg="red", bg="white")
        label.pack()

        self.labelVariable.set(u"Modélisation de populations atteintes d'un virus")

        v=Listbox(self.main)
        v.insert("end","Modèle SIR")
        v.insert("end", "Modèle de Witowski")
        v.insert("end", "Modèle de Munz")
        v.insert("end", "Modèle avec traitement")
        v.bind("<Double-Button-1>", self.Double)
        v.pack(expand=1,fill=BOTH)

    def Double(self,event):
        widget    = event.widget
        selection = widget.curselection()
        value     = widget.get(selection[0])
        self.newWindow(value)

    def ModifyTextarea(self,elem,msg,clear=None):
        elem.config(state=NORMAL)
        if clear:
            elem.delete(1.0, END)
        else:
            elem.insert(END,msg)
        elem.config(state=DISABLED)

    def newWindow(self,msg):
        top = Toplevel(self.root)
        q1 = Frame(top)
        q1.pack()
        top.grab_set()
        text = Text(q1,state=DISABLED,exportselection=True)
        text.pack()
        lbl = Label(q1,text="")
        lbl.pack()
        self.ModifyTextarea(text,msg)
        e1=Entry(q1)
        label1 = Label(self.main, textvariable="Taux de mortalité des zombies")
        e2=Entry(q1)
        e3=Entry(q1)
        e4=Entry(q1)
        e5=Entry(q1)
        label1.pack()
        e1.pack()
        e2.pack()
        e3.pack()
        e4.pack()
        e5.pack()
        e1.insert(10,"Taux de mortalité des zombies")
        e2.insert(10,"Coefficient de propagation du virus")
        e3.insert(10,"Taux de rémission")
        e4.insert(10,"Taux d'infectés devenant malades")
        e5.insert(10,"Taux de guérison")

        btnquit = Button(q1,borderwidth = 1,text = "Ok",command =lambda: top.destroy())
        btnquit.pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = GUI()
```

---

Here are the problems:

- I have no idea how to get the value of what was chosen in the listbox to be reused for the "if".
- I really don't know how to get he numerical values of what was put in the entry boxes. I do understand that I have to use a .get but I only get it to print it, not to use it in further functions.
- This is way less important but I tried putting labels next to the entry widgets but they don't show up. Any ideas why?

---

Just to give you an idea of what kind of function follows the GUI:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def zombies(a,b,ze,d,c,T,N,dt) :
    n = T/dt
    n=int(n)
    t=np.zeros((n+1))
    for i in range (0,n):
        t[0]=0
        t[i+1]=t[i]+dt
    s = np.zeros((n+1))
    e = np.zeros((n+1))
    z = np.zeros((n+1))
    r = np.zeros((n+1))
    s[0] = N
    z[0] =1
    r[0] = 0
    for i in range (n-1):
        s[i+1] = s[i]+dt*(-b*s[i]*z[i]-d*s[i]+c*z[i])
        e[i+1]= e[i]+dt*(b*s[i]*z[i]-ze*e[i]-d*e[i])
        z[i+1] = z[i]+dt*(-a*s[i]*z[i]+ze*e[i]-c*z[i])
        r[i+1] = r[i]+dt*(a*s[i]*z[i]+d*s[i]+d*e[i])
        if s[i+1]<0 or s[i+1] >N:
            s[i+1]=0
            break
        if e[i+1] > N or e[i+1] < 0:
            e[i+1]=0
            break
        if z[i+1] > N or z[i+1] < 0:
            z[i+1]=0
            break

        if r[i+1] <0 or r[i+1] >N:
            break
    return (t,s,r,z,e,i+2)
```

Comment: After you figure-out how to get the values from the GUI, generally speaking, you can call functions to do the follow-on processing by first importing the script they are in, i.e. `import othermodule`, and then calling them with i.e. `othermodule.zombies(..arguments-from-gui...)`. This call could be made to happen when a new button you'll have to add to your GUI is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

For Tkinter's Listbox, you must use `my_listbox.curselection()` to retrieve whatever is currently selected. I see you're using that in your `Double()` function.

To use this value later on, you should make `Double()` return something. It is a method, after all.

```
def Double(self,event):
    widget    = event.widget
    selection = widget.curselection()
    value     = widget.get(selection[0])
    self.newWindow(value)

    # this is the new part
    return value
```

Or if you're just talking about using these variables within the same class, you should use `self.`

```
def Double(self,event):
    widget    = event.widget
    self.selection = widget.curselection()
    self.value     = widget.get(selection[0])
    self.newWindow(value)
```

Now you can access `self.selection`, `self.value` anywhere in the class. But you must prefix them with `self.` or else it won't access the correct variable.

Comment: I have used that one in the function "double". But how do I get it our of the GUI into another function ?

Comment: I have updated my answer to better reflect the question.